# Conflict between own jQuery include and jQuery Tools include

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I need these two includes for different jQuery features but when they're included together they're conflicting and breaking each other. I can only include one or the other successfully but then I lose the other features.

Is there a way I can combine the features of these two includes without them clashing?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

I need the first include for the accordion at http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/
I need the second include for http://www.stickyjs.com

Comment: Try to change order of including

Comment: jQuery tools has a version that includes jQuery library right in the plugin file and one that doesn't. Use the one without if you want to manage your own version of jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and thank you for the re-ordering reminder. I used that along with replacing one of the includes with google's cdn for jquery. This worked and both functionalities remain in tact. The order is important:

```
<!-- Required for accordion -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Required for sticky nav -->
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still needlessly loading 2 versions of the jQuery library which is unnecessary overhead